# Setting Toolbar Button Style to BTNS_DROPDOWN

Tags: c++, atl

I am creating a Extension for Internet Explorer using C++ and ATL. And I am trying to change the style of my custom toolbar button Using below code

```
       // inject the drop down arrow
   bool CBHO::setButtonMenu(HWND hWndToolbar, int buttonID){
   TBBUTTONINFO inf;
    inf.cbSize=sizeof(inf);
    inf.dwMask=TBIF_STYLE;
    inf.fsStyle=BTNS_DROPDOWN | BTNS_AUTOSIZE ;

 if(SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_SETBUTTONINFO, (WPARAM)buttonID, (LPARAM)&inf))
    return true;
   return false;
       }
```

But an exception is thrown at SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_SETBUTTONINFO, .....

Unhandled exception at 0x74730EC5 (comctl32.dll) in iexplore.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation 
reading location 0x035CD434.

The hWndToolbar is correct as I already got the correct buttonText and buttonID using same hWndToolbar.

Please suggest how to correct this error. and how to Change the style of my button to a dropdown button.

Comment: Try zeroing out the structure, as in `TBBUTTONINFO inf = {0};`

Comment: i tried setting inf={0}; It doesn't make any difference. i am getting the same exception. 
call stack- comctl32.dll!CToolbar::TB_OnSetButtonInfo(int,struct TBBUTTONINFOW const *)